# Square to Kite Transformation Matrix

Tags: matrices, linear-transformations

Is there a matrix that transform points in the unit square to points in a kite with vertices $(0,0), (1-h,0), (1,1), (0,1-h)$?

It is known that there are matrix transformations to rotate, scale, or shear the unit square. But it is not clear if there is a matrix that performs the transformation described above.

Comment: Is that a linear transformation? If not, how can there be a matrix?